# How to update or delete fullCalendar Event with Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar

I dont know how update or delete fullcalendar events on my symfony project.

To add a new event, i open a modal window with a form to submit a new event and insert it in my database.

This is my controler(it work fine):

```
$datas = array();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($datas)
        ->add('title',  TextType::class)
        ->add('startDate', TextType::class, array(
            'attr'=> array('class' => 'dateTimePicker')))
        ->add('endDate', TextType::class, array(
            'attr'=> array('class' => 'dateTimePicker')))
        ->add('backgroundColor', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => $color ))

        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    /** Création d'un nouvel évenement */
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $title = $form->get('title')->getData();
        $start = new \DateTime($form->get('startDate')->getData());
        $end = new \DateTime($form->get('endDate')->getData());
        $backgroundColor = $form->get('backgroundColor')->getData();

        $event = new CalendarEvent();
        $event->setTitle($title);
        $event->setStartDate($start);
        $event->setEndDate($end);
        $event->setBackgroundColor($backgroundColor);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ma_lrm_accueil'));
    }
```

I know that to update events, i have to have a javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    timezone: ('Europe/London'),
    businessHours: {
        start: '09:00',
        end: '18:30',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    allDaySlot: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    lazyFetching: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    selectable: true,
    /*timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'h:mmt',
        '': 'h:mmt'
    },*/
    editable: true,
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    events: 'http://localhost/ligne_rh/web/app_dev.php/admin/accueil/calendar',

    eventResize: function(events) {
        console.log("Entrée dans : eventResize");
        var start1 = events.start.format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
        var end1 = events.end.format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/.../calendar/event/update',
            data: 'title=' + events.title + '&start=' + start1 + '&end=' + end1 + '&id=' + events.id,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("...");
            },
        });
    },

});
```

I dont understand any of it and i have no idea what my controler should look like.

Please HELP ME with an example!! I am novice!! thank you!!!!

Comment: what do you really want? go some errors ?

Comment: I dont know how my updateAction should look like?? should it return JSON and how??? I dont understand the link between my js and my action controler

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$em->merge($event);
```

for updating already existing entity and

```
$em->remove($event);
```

for removing entity.

Also maybe you should try to create different controller actions(eventDeleteAction, eventCreateAction) to make CRUD operations.

Comment: Just realized that it is not very helpfull since you completly new to programming and it is likely that this code is written by somebody else. I belive you should start with following articles and https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html, https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html,
https://blog.intelligentbee.com/2015/01/19/symfony-2-forms-and-ajax/ if you at least could run this code and familiar with basic programming terms like conditionals, loops and so on. Than I belive I could help you with other controllers code if you'll get any questions in process. Hope that would help!

Comment: ok thank you!! precisely, i dont know how my action should do the link with my javascript??

Comment: First of all you should define some controls inside your HTML to manage inserts and deletions(of course, if this operations should be done manually by user). Then, add some onClick handlers to make AJAX request if you want to do it asynchronous. You should specify urls which triggers your controllers inside your ajax calls to make your controllers run. I belive you could successfully google each and every word and get more detailed explanations on html controls, Javascript events and ajax. Also you will need some help of routing.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use https://github.com/tattali/CalendarBundle the documentation explain how to link the calendar to a CRUD to allow create, update and delete events